# QT 5.8 WebEngine Html 5 Video player support

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

I have created a Qt 5.8 web engine based application but unfortunately, the video is not playing in the application.

After coming across many forums I found that I need to build QT with flag proprietary-codec

But this solution comes with the warning: When distributing proprietary codec libraries, you must acquire licenses for them.

Unfortunately, I can't use these proprietary codec libraries.

If I use open source codec libraries do I need to compile QT again with some other flag.
Is there any other solution to this approach.

Comment: What is the format/codec of your video?

Comment: I am using mp4 videos.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for mp4 file format using proprietary codecs is the only option (i.e. this includes acquiring licenses to distribute and configuring/building Qt with the option you specified already in your question).

From [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html):

> Qt WebEngine supports the MPEG-4 Part 14 (MP4) file format only if the required proprietary audio and video codecs, such as H.264 and MPEG layer-3 (MP3), have been enabled.